# SQL Query within Excel Too Few Parameters Error

Tags: sql, excel

I have an SQL query which I created using the wizard and then modified a bit.  This query needs to pull data from two sheets in the same workbook.  Below is my slightly modified code:

```
SELECT `'TA Submissions$'`.`TA Content`, `'TA Submissions$'`.`Subject of TA`, `'TA Submissions$'`.`Unit of TA`, `'TA Submissions$'`.`Title of TA`, `'TA Submissions$'`.`Any Notes for the Invigilator or student?`, `TAs$`.`Group Code`, `TAs$`.`TA Code`, `TAs$`.`Extra Time`, `TAs$`.Student, `TAs$`.Subject, `TAs$`.Teacher, `TAs$`.Day, `TAs$`.Start, `TAs$`.Finish, `TAs$`.Duration, `TAs$`.`TA Subject`
FROM `'TA Submissions$'` `'TA Submissions$'`, `TAs$` `TAs$`
WHERE `TAs$`.Teacher+` - `+`TAs$`.`TA Subject` = `'TA Submissions$'`.`Teacher Name & Class Group` AND ((`TAs$`.`Submitted?`='Yes')) AND ((`TAs$`.`Generated?`<>'Generated'))
```

I don't usually use SQL so could anyone point me in the right direction please!  I've only found threads going from Access to Excel rather than Excel to Excel.

Many Thanks.

Comment: How does this relate to Excel? From where are you performing the query? If from Excel using VBA, what connector are you using and can you please include your code.  Also you mention SQL in your question but tag it as "mysql". Which database software are you using? Can you include at the very least a basic explanation of your database strucutre?

Comment: I'm not using VBA or any database.  I have used the Get External Data From Microsoft Query Wizard in Excel.  The two sources of data I am trying to combine are both sheets in the very same spreadsheet that I am trying to run the query, they are 'TAs' and 'TA Submissions'. Having created the query I then needed to go into it's properties to edit the SQL as I need it to concatenate two columns from TAs and compare the result to a column in TA Submissions, the wizard doesn't give me that option.  The code I placed in the question is the SQL in said properties.  Cont. in next comment.

Comment: Re the tag, I used MySQL because I wasn't sure which type of SQL Excel is using and I couldn't see just plain SQL.  Which tag should I be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most SQL dialects, to concatenate fields, you would use the ampersand `&` while the plus (`+`) signifies the addition operator and hyphen (`-`) signifies the subtraction operator.

Consider the following adjustment in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT  `'TA Submissions$'`.`TA Content`, `'TA Submissions$'`.`Subject of TA`, 
        `'TA Submissions$'`.`Unit of TA`, `'TA Submissions$'`.`Title of TA`,
        `'TA Submissions$'`.`Any Notes for the Invigilator or student?`, 
        `TAs$`.`Group Code`, `TAs$`.`TA Code`, `TAs$`.`Extra Time`, 
        `TAs$`.Student, `TAs$`.Subject, `TAs$`.Teacher, 
        `TAs$`.Day, `TAs$`.Start, `TAs$`.Finish, `TAs$`.Duration, `TAs$`.`TA Subject`
  FROM  `'TA Submissions$'` `'TA Submissions$'`, `TAs$` `TAs$`
 WHERE  `TAs$`.Teacher & `TAs$`.`TA Subject` =
        `'TA Submissions$'`.`Teacher Name & Class Group` 
   AND  ((`TAs$`.`Submitted?`='Yes')) AND ((`TAs$`.`Generated?`<>'Generated'))
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  I knew it had to be something simple.  I just changed the where to `WHERE  `TAs$`.Teacher & " - " & `TAs$`.`TA Subject` =
        `'TA Submissions$'`.`Teacher Name & Class Group` `
and I was away!